# How can I compile a mining software for my mac computer that uses an NVIDIA GPU?

Tags: gpu-mining, mining-pools, mining-theory, compile

Please, don't ask me why.

I have a computer that runs OS X on it with a NVIDIA GPU card. I would like to compile my mining software for GPU mining, but I don't find any info at all about this on the internet.c'est

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You want tsiv's [ccminer-cryptonight](https://github.com/tsiv/ccminer-cryptonight).

I've never successfully compiled it on macOS, and don't have a mac desktop anymore to test it on, but I believe a few recent Issues on github answer this question...

https://github.com/tsiv/ccminer-cryptonight/issues/9

https://github.com/tsiv/ccminer-cryptonight/issues/6

Your best bet is to try to follow the build instructions there, maybe follow up on one of those issues if you have similar problems, and see what you can do. If you succeed, you should post the full compile process here as the "Accepted Answer" unless someone else answers better than me before then.